# SCNScene - Not rendering changes to SKNode made on touchesBegan handler

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I'm subclassing SKNode and implemening the touchbegan handler.

**When user clicks on the node, the node position is changed but the node does not move on screen.**

I guess i need to force rendering of the SKScene somehow.

To test i did the following minor changes to the template for games of xcode6. 
Here the changes to the template:

GameViewControler.swift

```
 let HUD = SKScene(fileNamed: "HUD.sks") 
 scnView.overlaySKScene = HUD

 var customNode = CustomNode()
 customNode.text = "touch here"
 customNode.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
 HUD.addChild(customNode)
```

New class CustomeNode.swift

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

public class CustomNode:SKLabelNode{

public override init() {
    super.init();
    userInteractionEnabled = true;
}

public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

public override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    position.y = (position.y + 100) % 300 + 100; //does not update on screen
}
```

}

If add back the action for the ship it works:

```
let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!
    ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))
```

how to force rendering?

**UPDATE**
To clarify the complete code of GameViewControler.swift, removing everthing that is not needed.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.dae") //comes with XCode6 Game Project Template.

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

         // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as SCNView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let HUD = SKScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
        scnView.overlaySKScene = HUD
        scnView.overlaySKScene.userInteractionEnabled = true;

        var customNode = CustomNode()
        customNode.text = "touch here"
        customNode.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
        HUD.addChild(customNode)

        //let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!
        //ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the touchesBegan method runs?

Comment: Yes, it runs. To work i just need to have a running some action on scene

Comment: You are mixing `SK` (Sprite Kit) and `SCN` (Scene Kit) in that code. Is your question about one or the other? Or are you using both?

Comment: I'm using both. The HUD object (SKScene) is passed to overlaySKScene property of the SCNView. I added the complete GameViewController class code for clarification to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple add at viewDidLoad bottom:

```
scnView.play(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

[scene.view setNeedsDisplay:YES]
or
[node.scene.view setNeedsDisplay:YES]

Comment: SKScene has no NeedsDiplay property.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem using:

```
self.gameView!.playing = true;
self.gameView!.loops = true;
```